# Forward a move reference through a function, without writing the function twice

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Recently I often encountered the problem, that I had to write a function which takes an input as a const reference. But at some point this function (usually a constructor) calls another function which could use the input as a move reference. For that reason I usually created a copy of the function to allow const reference and move reference, i.e.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

void foo(const A&  a) { std::cout << "Reference" << std::endl; }

void foo(      A&& a) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }

void bar(const A& a) {
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::move(a));
}

void bar(A&& a) {
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::move(a));
}

int main() {
    A a;
    bar(a);
    bar(A());
}
```

However it is obviously pretty ugly to copy `bar` two times with the only difference being the signature and the `std::move`. One alternative I know would be to make `bar` a tempalte function and to use `std::forward`, but I don't want to do that because it would allow any parameter type to be passed to `bar` (especially since in my real application bar is an implicit constructor).

So my question is: Is there any other way to forward a move reference through a function without writing it twice?

Comment: "*[...] to make bar a tempalte function [...], but I don't want to do that because it would allow any parameter type to be passed to bar*" you can easily disallow other types to be passed in, `static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, typename std::decay<T>::type>{}, "!");`, or through SFINAE

Comment: @PiotrS. This would give a compile time error, but `bar` would still take part in the overload resolution, wouldn't it? In particular if `bar` is a constructor (of the class `bar`) and I have a function `test` with the overloads `test(bar x)` and `test(std::string x)`, then a call to `test("A test")` would cause the compiler to complain about ambiguity since the char array is implicitly convertible to `std::string` and `bar` (although the latter would still cause an error afterwards)?

Comment: that's why I suggested SFINAE as a possible alternative as well

Comment: see it [here in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30fe01633949de74)

Comment: or better, [with an expression sfinae](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c52e6382c64000e0)

Comment: @PiotrS. : Oh cool. I have no experience with the SFINAE concept yet, but your example looks great! I tried to use it in the constructor (where I have no return parameter), but apparently I miss something. My attempt: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1032ad53b1a611d1 .

Comment: here is your corrected code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7db7e7d08bb3caad

Comment: [and you can use the expression sfinae in a constructor as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57dae6c063c0b092)

Comment: @PiotrS. Wow, cool. Thank you very much. If you want post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to accept both rvalues and lvalues in a single function, retaining the possibility to restore the value category of its argument, you can use a *forwarding-reference*. You can easily restrict the type of arguments passed in utilizing the *expression SFINAE* technique, which in your case will verify if the call `foo(std::forward<T>(a))` is well-formed. If not, that function will be excluded from the set of viable functions during the overload resolution:

#### Option #1

Hide the *expression SFINAE* in a trailing return type:

```
template <typename T>
auto bar(T&& a)
    -> decltype(void(foo(std::forward<T>(a))))
{
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4b20283995abcdb)

#### Option #2

Hide the *expression SFINAE* in a template parameters list:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = decltype(foo(std::forward<T>(std::declval<T&>())))>
void bar(T&& a)
{
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c850eafd91573487)

The latter approach is especially useful for constructors (which don't specify a return type):

```
struct Bar
{
    template <typename T,
              typename = decltype(foo(std::forward<T>(std::declval<T&>())))>
    Bar(T&& a)
    {
        foo(std::forward<T>(a));
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f35493abcf5737b)

Comment: Ouch, I was too late.

Comment: @Columbo especially that this approach was discussed in the comments under the question about 20 minutes ago

Comment: I am aware that it was discussed. I am talking about the answer. (The approach itself is trivial.)

Answer (score 2):

Perfect forwarding with SFINAE works and keeps the overload set unpolluted. You first have to decide what exactly should be checked, e.g. the type set this template should be invoked for or expressions that should be valid.
Here, both suffice - this code checks the type:

```
// Helper template:
template <typename T, typename U, typename R=void>
using enable_if_compatible = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,
    typename std::remove_cv<
      typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type>::value, R>::type;

// Possible usage:
template <typename T>
enable_if_compatible<T, A> bar(T&& a)
{
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8172c93b0af351eb).
The following one depends on the validity of the call to `foo` and should be more flexible.

```
template <typename T>
auto bar(T&& a) -> decltype(void(foo(std::forward<T>(a))))
{
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    foo(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39952e38e7095f27).

Comment: @dyp I guess I'll have to take `remove_cv<remove_reference<>>` then, which is rather ugly.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe someone should propose a `is_forward_compatible` trait.

Comment: @dyp I started with [`remove_cv_reference`](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/lJqeyyBI6W4), let's see how well that goes first ;)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a templated version of `bar` that takes a pointer to `foo` and contains all of the common code that is currently in existing implementations of `bar`.

```
template<class T>
void bar(T&& a, void (*f)(T&&a))
{
    //Other things, which treat "a" as a const reference
    f(std::move(a));
}
void bar(const A&  a)
{
    bar<const A&>(a, foo);
}

void bar(A&& a)
{
    bar(std::move(a), foo);
}
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly specify the template arguments?